# disable public_activity tracking for sidekiq jobs that require current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, public-activity

In short I get an error that `public_activity` is looking for the `current_user` while updating a model during a `sidekiq` job. That is expected since there is no `current_user`....  how do I disable `public_activity` tracking while the job is running? I've tried change `PublicActivity.enabled = false` and `Prospect.public_activity_off` during the job, but the `tracked owner: Proc.new{ |controller, model| controller.current_user }` still seems to be picking it up and looking for the `current_user`

How can I have the `sidekiq` (or any job) make updates without `public_activity` interfering ?

Would it be better to have `sidekiq` set the `current_user` to a dummy user during the job? I don't think this would be a good idea, because then we would need to filter that out later.

Error:

```
2016-04-20T17:24:53.728Z 20447 TID-owpsaw07w ProspectDataAggregationWorker JID-bad79ab6a073d57d7388e931 INFO: start
2016-04-20T17:24:53.739Z 20447 TID-owpsaw07w ProspectDataAggregationWorker JID-bad79ab6a073d57d7388e931 INFO: fail: 0.01 sec
2016-04-20T17:24:53.739Z 20447 TID-owpsaw07w WARN: {"class"=>"ProspectDataAggregationWorker", "args"=>[1], "retry"=>false, "queue"=>"default", "jid"=>"bad79ab6a073d57d7388e931", "created_at"=>1461173093.728181, "enqueued_at"=>1461173093.7282372}
2016-04-20T17:24:53.739Z 20447 TID-owpsaw07w WARN: NoMethodError: undefined method `current_user' for nil:NilClass
2016-04-20T17:24:53.739Z 20447 TID-owpsaw07w WARN: /Users/cj/RubymineProjects/revenue_management_system/app/models/prospect.rb:3:in `block in <class:Prospect>'
/Users/cj/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/public_activity-1.5.0/lib/public_activity/common.rb:14:in `resolve_value'
/Users/cj/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/public_activity-1.5.0/lib/public_activity/common.rb:315:in `prepare_relation'
/Users/cj/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/public_activity-1.5.0/lib/public_activity/common.rb:281:in `prepare_settings'
/Users/cj/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/public_activity-1.5.0/lib/public_activity/common.rb:250:in `create_activity'
/Users/cj/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/public_activity-1.5.0/lib/public_activity/actions/update.rb:14:in `activity_on_update'
/Users/cj/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:432:in `block in make_lambda'
```

Full error: https://gist.github.com/cdesch/190c46c69213a37e4162e50727531761

Model:

```
class Prospect < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PublicActivity::Model
  tracked owner: Proc.new{ |controller, model| controller.current_user }
      ...
    end
```

Sidekiq Job/worker

```
class ProspectDataAggregationWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  sidekiq_options :retry => false # job will be discarded immediately if failed

  def perform(account_id)
    #Prospect.public_activity_off
    PublicActivity.enabled = false

    account = Account.where(id: account_id).first
    prospects = account.prospects

    prospects.each do |prospect|
      prospect.update_based_on_primary_assessment!
    end
    PublicActivity.enabled = true

    #Prospect.public_activity_on
  end
end
```

I have also posted this same question in the [public_activity issues](https://github.com/chaps-io/public_activity/issues/259)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue ultimately was not `sidekiq` or `public_activity` gems. Doing Prospect.public_activity_off worked  (below), even though I previously stated it did not. The issue was that the `sidekiq` process was caching the models and workers, thus any changes I was making to the to the models were not taking effect until `sidekiq` was recycled/restarted. After which, the following functions worked fine.

```
def perform(account_id)

   Prospect.public_activity_off
   ...
end
```

or the following:

```
class ApplicationWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

   def perform(*args)
     PublicActivity.without_tracking { super(*args) }
   end
end
```

The issue at heart was not a code issue, but a developer issue. :-) Restart `sidekiq` after making worker changes!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the problem by before this issue will be resolved if you rescue your error:

```
tracked owner: Proc.new do |controller, model| 
  controller.current_user rescue nil_or_User_new_or_something_else
end
```